# until the weather shall permit my embarkation

Tags: modal-verbs, will-shall

I am wondering how the modal "shall" affects the interepratation of the following sentence in traditional British English:

> My voyage is only now delayed until the weather **shall** permit my embarkation.

Does the until-clause mean the same as "until **I am certain** the weahter permits my embarkation"?

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat formal way of saying **until the weather permits**.

The question of certainty doesn't arise.

Comment: Are you British?

Comment: From _Frankenstein_ by Mary Wollstonecraft Shelley (written 1818). Very  old fashioned, bordering on archaic. Apollyon, please state origin of material you ask questions about.